# Is it allowed to resign appstore apps for enterprise distribution?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

My manager is asking me to get an app (free app, not our app) from the appstore and resign it with our enterprise account and distribute it with our MDM tool.

Is this allowed by Apple?

Or will this possibly result in our enterprise account being terminated by Apple?

Comment: It should not, we have an app that is both in the Appstore and available as an InHouse App. But we do have different bundle id for both apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every app has a specific code given by the app store which even if resigned CANNOT CHANGE...it it the same as how youtube identifies reuploaded videos and informs the actual copyright owner...apple's t and c clearly state that it may result in being banned or complete account termination
a statement from the t and c 
**(vi) iTunes Plus Products do not contain security technology that limits your usage of such Products, and Usage Rules (ii) – (v) do not apply to iTunes Plus Products. You may copy, store, and burn iTunes Plus Products as reasonably necessary for personal, noncommercial use.**
rules ii-v are simply not required here